# Problem with brackets in regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

can anybody help me with regular expression in C#?
I want to create a pattern for this input:

```
{a? ab 12 ?? cd}
```

This is my pattern:

```
([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})+
```

The problem are the curly brackets. This doesn't work:

```
{(([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})+)}
```

It just works for

```
{ab}
```

Comment: Maybe `{(?:([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})(?: (?!}))?)+}`? `{(?:\s*([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}))+}`? Do you want to match if there are spaces after `{` or before `}`?

Comment: Like this? `{([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}(?: [A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})*)+}` https://regex101.com/r/H15sJw/1

Comment: https://regexr.com/5lkf8

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right. My bad. The one brace that has no special meaning in regex. I'll delete my original comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: Does [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024580/3832970) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow leading/trailing whitespace within `{...}` string, the expression will look like

```cs
{(?:\s*([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}))+\s*}
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%28%5BA-Fa-f0-9%3F%5D%7B2%7D%29%29%2B%5Cs*%7D&i=%7Ba%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%7D%20%7B%20a%3F%20%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7Ba%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7B%20%20%20a%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%7D)

If you only allow a single regular space only between the values inside `{...}` and no space after `{` and before `}`, you can use

```cs
{(?:([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})(?: (?!}))?)+}
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%3F%3A%28%5BA-Fa-f0-9%3F%5D%7B2%7D%29%28%3F%3A%20%28%3F!%7D%29%29%3F%29%2B%7D&i=%7Ba%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%7D%20%7B%20a%3F%20%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7Ba%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7B%20%20%20a%3F%20ab%2012%20%3F%3F%20cd%7D). Note this one is much stricter. *Details*:

- `{` - a `{` char
- `(?:\s*([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}))+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})` - Capturing group 1: two hex or `?` chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `}` - a `}` char.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MORUME):

```cs
var text = "{a? ab 12 ?? cd}";
var pattern = @"{(?:([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})(?: (?!}))?)+}";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value))
        .ToList();
foreach (var list in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", list));
// => a?; ab; 12; ??; cd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture pairs of chars between the curly's, you can use a single capture group:

```
{([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}(?: [A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})*)}
```

*Explanation*

- `{` Match `{`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}` Match 2 times any of the listed characters
  - `(?: [A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})*` Optionally repeat a space and again 2 of the listed characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `}` Match `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iddl9i/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EWgYDE)

*Example code*

```
string pattern = @"{([A-Fa-f0-9?]{2}(?: [A-Fa-f0-9?]{2})*)}";
        string input = @"{a? ab 12 ?? cd}
{ab}";
        
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

*Output*

```
a? ab 12 ?? cd
ab
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `{([A-Fa-f0-9?]+|[^}]+)}`

It captures 1 group which:

1. Match a single character present in the list below  `[A-Fa-f0-9?]+`
2. Match a single character not present in the list below `[^}]+`